# EF Web API JSON post using textarea input causes SQL exception

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

When trying to configure a demo Web API I run into an issue with a POST request. Using a textarea to allow users to copy/paste a list of parms from Excel, the EF code throws a SQL Exception that string or binary data would be trucated. This happens with only 5 records. However if I use Fiddler and create the JSON manually I can have a list of over 300 records. The only thing I can see being different is the control characters being added by the code. Below is a what I see generated by the code which does throw the error

```
{"parmType_ID":"1","appuser_ID":1,"request_NAME":"test-5-from-screen","rawInputParmList":"AB00000003\nAB00000004\nAB00000005\nAB00000006\nAB00000008","saveRequest":true}
```

If I just edit that request to remove the \n it works fine

```
{"parmType_ID":"1","appuser_ID":1,"request_NAME":"test-5-from-fiddler","rawInputParmList":"AE00000003
AE00000004
AE00000005
AE00000006
AE00000008","saveRequest":true}
```

Here is the JQuery call

```
    function addRequest() {
        var reportid = $('#selReports').val();
        var parmtypeid = $('#selParmTypes').val();
        var requestname = $('#txtRequestName').val();
        var inputparms = $('#txtInputParms').val();
        var dataObject = {
            'parmType_ID': parmtypeid,
            'appuser_ID': 1,
            'request_NAME': requestname,
            'rawInputParmList': inputparms,
            'saveRequest': true
        };
        console.log(dataObject);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'api/ReportRequest',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

Should I be doing something to that textarea before I make the call?

Comment: I would, either before passing to the controller, or after the controller receives it and before sticking it in the database, parse out the rawInputParmList in to a list<string>.

Comment: I did a quick test in both JQuery and the Controller to replace \n with a comma and it works. But I don't understand why 3000 records with a comma are fine but 10 records with \n cause the SQL exception. Clearly it isn't an overflow based on string size. I can mark this complete later unless someone knows why the \n is so special.

Comment: when you receive rawInputParmList in the controller, I am assuming you receive it as a single string, what is the length in the different methods you submitted it?

Comment: The rawInputParmList is a string in the controller, in the SQL SP it is a varchar(max). I've used this SQL SP with an old ASP.Net application and had no issues with up to 8000 parms. I think the SQL Exception is very misleading for some reason because it can't be a truncation issue. As for the length it would be whatever the difference is between the having the \n and then removing it with something like rawInputParmList.Replace("\n", ",") . But with the \n it halts at 5 values and without I can enter up to 3000.